# Tailwind plugin cannot be activated

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I know it's a question that is annoying, but I don't know what else I can do. I would like to use an external tailwind plugin. I am just no able activated that and  don't know why.

Name: `tailwindcss-neumorphism`

GitHub: https://github.com/sambeevors/tailwindcss-neumorphism

I am using NextJs and just running `npm run dev` after the configuration

tailwind.config.js

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    `./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}`,
    `./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}`,
  ],
  plugins: [require('tailwindcss-neumorphism')],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      black: colors.black,
      white: colors.white,
      gray: colors.trueGray,
      indigo: colors.indigo,
      red: colors.rose,
      yellow: colors.amber,
      blue: colors.blue,
      trueGray: colors.trueGray,
      purple: colors.purple,
      primary: '#4338CA',
      secondary: '#2563EB',
      tertiary: '#171717',
      text: {
        primary: '#F3F4F6',
        secondary: '#9CA3AF',
      },
    },

    neumorphismColor: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      black: colors.black,
      white: colors.white,
      gray: colors.trueGray,
      indigo: colors.indigo,
      red: colors.rose,
      yellow: colors.amber,
      blue: colors.blue,
      trueGray: colors.trueGray,
      purple: colors.purple,
      primary: '#4338CA',
      secondary: '#2563EB',
      tertiary: '#171717',
    },
    neumorphismSize: {
      xs: '0.05em',
      sm: '0.1em',
      default: '0.2em',
      lg: '0.4em',
      xl: '0.8em',
    },
    boxShadow: {
      sm: '0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)',
      DEFAULT:
        '0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)',
      md: '0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)',
      lg: '0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)',
      xl: '0 20px 25px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)',
      '2xl': '0 25px 50px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)',
      '3xl': '0 35px 60px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
      inner: 'inset 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)',
      none: 'none',
      homepageInner:
        'inset 10px 0px 22px 20px #171717, inset -5px 0 65px 37px  #171717',
    },
  },
  variants: {
    neumorphismFlat: ['responsive'],
    neumorphismConcave: false,
    neumorphismConvex: ['responsive', 'hover'],
    neumorphismInset: ['focus', 'active'],
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Remove your `plugins: []` in the last line.

Comment: omg j... wtf. I really did not see that